Topology of the valence Bloch bundle for a $d = 2$ Chern insulator
I am currently working on topological insulators, and I'm reading the review An introduction to topological insulators by Carpentier and Fruchart. In this review, they use the fiber bundle language to characterize topological insulators. Let me introduce the notations before I present what troubles me. I'll try to detail as much as possible what I understood, so that it is as clear as possible.
We consider a lattice in $d=2$, so the quasi momentum living on the 2-torus $\vec{k}\in T^2$ is a good quantum number. At each point of this manifold, the dynamics of an electron is described by a Bloch Hamiltonian $H(\vec{k})$. By denoting $\mathcal{H}_{\vec{k}}$ the Hilbert space on which $H(\vec{k})$ acts, we assign at each point of the torus, a 2-dimensional Hilbert space. Thus, we have a vector bundle where the base space is $T^2$, and the fibers are $\mathcal{H}_\vec{k}\cong \mathbb{C}^2$. In the review, they claim that this bundle is always trivial, which is a point I haven't understood yet.
Now, let's specify a bit the Hamiltonian (p.5). We consider the generic Bloch Hamiltonian
$$H(k) = h_0(\vec{k}) + \vec{h}(\vec{k})\cdot\vec{\sigma},$$ where $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)$ are the Pauli matrices. One may show that the eigenvalues $|u_{\pm}(\vec{k})\rangle$  of this Hamiltonian are given by $$|u_{\pm}(\vec{k})\rangle = \left(1+\dfrac{h_z + \epsilon_{\pm}^2}{h_x^2+h_y^2}\right)^{-1/2}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\epsilon_{\pm}}{h_x+ih_y} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\epsilon_{\pm}$ are the eigenvalues associated to the states $|u_{\pm}(\vec{k})\rangle$. Using the spectral theorem, the 2-dimensional Hilbert space is spanned by these states $$\mathcal{H}_\vec{k} = \text{span}\left( |u_{+}(\vec{k})\rangle, |u_{-}(\vec{k})\rangle\right).$$ As we are studying an insulator, there are two subspaces of $\mathcal{H}_\vec{k}$ that are well defined, namely  $$\mathcal{H}_\vec{k}^\pm = \text{span}\left( |u_{\pm}(\vec{k})\rangle\right)$$ As the bundle formed by the base space $T^2$ and the fibers $\mathcal{H}_\vec{k}$ is always trivial, we focus on Bloch bundle formed by the base space $T^2$ and the subspace $\mathcal{H}_{\vec{k}}^-$ describing the valence band. This sub-bundle can present non trivial topology.
One can parametrize $\vec{h}(\vec{k})$ using spherical coordinates $$\vec{h}(\vec{k}) = h(\vec{k}) \begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta_\vec{k}\sin\phi_\vec{k} \\
\sin\theta_\vec{k}\cos\phi_\vec{k} \\
\cos\theta_\vec{k}\end{pmatrix}.$$ Using this parametrization, one may show that $$|u_-(\vec{k})\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}-\sin\frac{\theta_\vec{k}}{2} \\ e^{i\phi_\vec{k}}\cos\frac{\theta_\vec{k}}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$
As the state $|u_-(\vec{k})\rangle$ is independent of the norm $h(\vec{k})$, we can set it to unity without changing the topology of $\mathcal{H}_{\vec{k}}$. Thus, the eigenvector $|u_-(\vec{k})\rangle$ is parametrized by the angles which parametrizes the 2-sphere $S^2$
In order to characterize the topology of this sub-bundle, we would like to compute the first Chern number $c_1$. The point is that $c_1\neq 0$ means that the bundle has a non trivial topology. To do so, we define a connexion 1-form (which is the Berry connexion here) on the base space $A$ and a curvature associated to this connexion $$F = \text{d}A.$$ The first Chern number can be computed using
$$ c_1 = \dfrac{i}{2\pi}\text{tr} F $$.
Here comes my problem: on the valence sub-bundle, the trace of the connexion is an integral over the whole Brillouin Zone, so an integral over $T^2$. If we wanted to compute this integral, we would need to find an open covering of $T^2$ and define locally the connexion 1-form on each of these open sets. However, in the review, they compute the curvature 2-form by integrating over the 2-sphere. They argue that it is because the elements of the subspace $\mathcal{H}_\vec{k}^-$ are parametrized by the angles of the 2-sphere. However, it doesn't really make sense to me : the 2-torus and the 2-sphere are topologically inequivalent, and the curvature is a 2-form on the base space, namely $T^2$. Thus, it seems like a magic trick trading the integration of the 2-form over $T^2$ by a simpler integral over $S^2$. If someone has a good explanation on this, I would love to read it.

I am not very familiar with this model. However, the $S^2=SU(2)/U(1)$ here is viewed as the coadjoint orbit of $SU(2)$, whose Lie algebra is spanned by the Pauli matrices. Due to the Kähler structure of the 2-sphere there exists a hermitian line bundle with connection $A$, which is the dual bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ of the tautological bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ also called hyperplane bundle. The curvature $F$ of the connection is related to the Kähler form $\omega$ by $F=2\pi i\omega$. Its integral over the sphere is 1/2. More importantly, in this context such a bundle is called pre-quantum line bundle. The space of polarized sections of this bundle $H^0(S^2,\mathcal{O}(1))$ is isomorphic to your Hilbert space and gives an irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ upon identifying the three operators acting on the space of sections. If you search for "geometric quantization of the two-sphere" you will find a more detailed explanation.

Thank you for this answer! Unfortunately, I don't have the background to fully understand what you explained here. Thank you for the reference, I'll definitely take a look!

It seems to me that in computing the Chern Number, the paper does in fact integrate over the Brillouin Zone. This is most clearly seen in equations (19)-(24), where one explicitly computes the number of times the map $h:T^2 \rightarrow S^2$ wraps around the 2-sphere. It is possible that equations (15)-(18), where it is less explicit that an integration over the torus is occurring, are what is giving you pause. Here they are using the fact that $h$ provides a pull back from the sphere to the torus (as they remark in a footnote).
If pullbacks and this kind of transformation are unfamiliar, I would recommend the appendix and differential geometry in Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons, and/or their chapter 8 which emphasizes topology in Condensed Matter applications.

Welcome to Physics.SE. Please note that answers should be self contained, and not rely heavily on following links. Otherwise your answer which may otherwise be very helpful, may be flagged as "not an answer" and removed. I suggest that you consider editing it. You can read more about this policy in Meta, in particular: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."
